# Is it possible to get values from etc/network/interface to my input tag?

Tags: javascript, python, html, linux, debian

I was wondering if there's a possible way to read non extension file from an input tag?

for example: I have an "IP" input tag, and I want to get values from etc / network/interface and the values I have on etc/network/interfaces over there must be shown in my input tag.

I'm not asking you to make me the source code, I'm asking if is it possible and which method should I use? tips are welcome! :)

I tried CGI python, tried JavaScript but I don't know how to open etc /network/interface.

Someone told me "try Python", I don't know much about Python, however I'm starting to learn about that, should I go ahead with Python?

***Thank you.***

Comment: if you are wanting this in a browser then only server code can access files. You can print the value while rendering page or make ajax request for it. What language you use is up to you based on server config

Comment: Even if the file is without extension for example etc/network/etc?

Comment: You can not access file system directly from inside browser for obvious security reasons. Your server can be on your local machine depending on what you are trying to do with this app. And there are lots of ways to quickly set one up